# How to send controls with .ashx Handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, ashx

I have a handler to get all image urls and other data from a mysql table in the ashx handler, but now i want to do a webcontrol (e.g: `Panel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div>Example</div>"));`) and send it to the page, to be displayed.

How can i do that if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to render server controls from a generic handler, however, you could return plain HTML and use javascript / jquery to display the returned HTML.

You can also build a server control structure, render it to a stringwriter and return the generated markup

See the answer here 
[Use ASP.Net server control code generation from .ashx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732257/use-asp-net-server-control-code-generation-from-ashx)